# Passing a non-empty list to a function

Tags: haskell, parameter-passing, tail

I have written this small function to retrieve the tail of a list:

```
let getTail l = if length l > 0 then tail l else "empty list"
```

Passing `[]`to `getTail` returns `empty list` but passing `[1,2,3]` gives the following error:

```
<interactive>:1:14:
No instance for (Num Char)
  arising from the literal `3'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num Char)
In the expression: 3
In the first argument of `getTail', namely `[1, 2, 3]'
In the expression: getTail [1, 2, 3]
```

I can't understand what that error means. What is the problem? Using GHCi 7.0.4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's think about the type of your `getTail` function. Initially, we can imagine `l` to be any list. The return type, however, has to be a `String` because you sometimes return `"empty list"`. Since that's part of an if statement where you might also return `tail l`, it means `l` *has to* be a `String`.

So your `getTail` function has type `String -> String`.

When you call `getTail` with `[1,2,3]`, it expects a `String`, which is just a `[Char]`. Remember that numeric literals are overloaded: `[1,2,3]` is equivalent to calling `[fromInteger 1, fromInteger 2, fromInteger 3]`. So, given this list, Haskell is trying to get a number from a `Char`. Since `Char`s are not part of the `Num` class, this fails, giving you your error.

A good solution would be to return a `Maybe` type and give `Nothing` for the error rather than returning `"empty list"`. So rewrite your function as:

```
let getTail l = if length l > 0 then Just (tail l) else Nothing
```

Now its type is `[a] -> Maybe [a]`. Using this will force anybody using your function to check whether `getTail` succeeded before being able to use the result.

Another option is to return `[]` in place of "empty list". In this case, your `getTail` function will work exactly like `drop 1`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Prelude> let getTail l = if length l > 0 then tail l else "empty list"
```

You didn't give `getTail` a type signature, so one is inferred.

```
Prelude> :t getTail
getTail :: [Char] -> [Char]
```

*`:t` gives you the type of anything in GHCi. This is extremely useful. Type signatures say a lot about a function in Haskell.*

This is probably not what you meant. Why does it only work on `[Char]`, (or equivalently, `String`), and not on any list?

Here's why:

A function can only have one return type. Since you return `"empty list"` when the list is empty, the return type must be `String`. It just so happens that the return type of `tail xs` where `xs` is a `[Char]` is also a `String`, which is why you don't get an error when you first define the function. Therefore your function as it is must be `[Char] -> [Char]`.

You're trying to call it with the argument `[1, 2, 3]`, which has a type of `Num a => a`. GHC is telling you "A `Char` doesn't have an instance of Num", or "I can't turn a number into a Char." This involves typeclasses—if you don't understand those yet, it doesn't matter, because you would still get an error of you tried `getTail ([1, 2, 3] :: [Int])`. You're trying to pass a list of `Int`s to a function that takes a list of `Char`s.

I would recommend reading through [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/introduction) to understand the Haskell type system.

Comment: I don't think the fact that he's in GHCi is important: that's the type that would be inferred anywhere.

Comment: I am reading that already :) I think i wrote that function without understanding function types (i read till `tail` and thought it was time i combined writing function that used an in-built function. Hence, the toy function)

Answer (score 1):

Should be rather `[]` instead of `"empty list"` (You are mixing types)

```
Prelude> let getTail l = if length l > 0 then tail l else []
Prelude> getTail [1, 2, 3]
[2,3]
```